# It is the browser a specie of virtual machine to javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, compilation, virtual-machine

Yes, it is a begginner question: I see javascript run inside browsers. So, every browser is a kind of a virtual machine (like in java) to run javascript code over it? I can't "compile" javascript  in any form?

Answer (score 4):

Right, you can't "compile" Javascript into anything else ahead of time. The browser compiles it for you, and then runs it. Some browsers have more sophisticated Javascript compilers than others.

Comment: @aviad: The authors of such things as [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) and [SpiderMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_(JavaScript_engine)) would disagree.

Comment: @aviad most of them do JIT compilation (which is what greg was talking about)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, well in some cases it is two-pass interpret without compile. It is browser-dependent. Look up WebKit's SquirrelFish Extreme and Google V8 to see what's at the fastest end of things, and look at Mozilla's JaegerMonkey for that implementation.

AFIAK V8 and SFX are JITs, so they compile JS code to native. JaegerMonkey and TraceMonkey combine in Firefox to form a system where if code would be faster traced, TraceMonkey executes it, and if code were faster native, JaegerMonkey compiles it, just like SFX

Comment: @Matt Briggs, please see above

Answer (score 2):

Each browser window and even each browser frame within that window is it's own HTML/javascript execution engine (similar to a virtual machine).

They are not each entirely independent because (subject to some security restrictions), they can communicate with each other and can know about each other, but they each have their execution state, their own global variables, their own code, their own event handlers, etc...

Javascript code isn't really compiled in the same sense that C/C++ code is compiled.  The browser only accepts javascript in text form.  The browser then interprets that text.  Different browsers have different ways of interpreting the javascript text in order to execute as quickly as possible.  it is not compiled directly into pure machine language like C/C++ code is, but rather compiled (or changed) into something that the interpreter can execute much faster than plain text.

Comment: The [V8 engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) JIT-compiles to machine code.

Comment: @GregHewgill - it can't be compiled into pure machine code unless nearly every single statement is nothing more than a function call to some JS interpreter function because javascript doesn't have hard types like machine code does.  For example, when I write x += 5 in JS, the result of compiling that cannot be machine code to add 5 to some register or some stack variable like it can be in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, browsers have a [JavaScript Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) running inside. This engine reads and executes JavaScript code . So, it is rather an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) (no compilation at all)